# Problem when doing a 3d-plot of a function

Tags: plotting, functions

So I have been working with *Mathematica* I have defined a function called `funcional` that receives $u, \alpha, \beta, y2 , x3 $ where the first one is a function of two variable to $\mathbb{R}$ and the other ones are constants. Now this basically integrates the function over a polytope with some constants that are determined by $ \alpha, \beta, y2 , x3 $ , the function works and it returns values for any function $u$ . Now I am interested in ploting how this function behaves for function of the type $Max[0,m*x+y]$ when $\alpha,\beta,y2,x3$ are fixed so I wrote this :

```
Plot3D[funcional[Max[0, m*x + y], 3/4, 3/4, 1, 1], {m, -10, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]
```

But when I do this it shows this error

> Invalid integration variable or limits in {x,0.0000715}$\in$Rectangle[{0,0},{1/4,3/4}].

Now this is weird because the function `funcional$ seems to be working when I insert any type of function or parameter that I want in it so I don't get why this error is showing up when I'm trying to plot.
Any help is apprecciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to use `Evaluate` on the first argument you give `Plot3D`?

Comment: What is `functional`?

Comment: It receives 4 parameters and a functions and returns a real number.

Comment: Yeah if i use Evalute it works Thanks man!